# Need help in opening sharepoint 2010 from designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

While i am opening the sharepoint 2010 intranet site with port number, i am successfully able to open the site from sharepoint desinger. But while i am trying to open the same site after configuring **Alternate Access Mapping**: For
example http://mydomainname.net i am getting below error: Let me explain how i am opening the site: I have typed the url: http://mydomainname.net
in the browser. Site got opened, then i went site settings, then clicked on open with designer.

```
unable to open the site. Possible causes:

1. The Web server many not have sharepoint Server installed.
2. The Web Server may be temprarily out of service.
3. If you are conneting through a proxy server, the proxy settings may be incorrect.
4. An error may have occurred in the Web server.
```

Please help somebody. your help is heartily appreicated.

Comment: Even with AAM, you should have the port number in place .. isn't it ?

Comment: This is not clear can u give the exact solution.

Comment: What happens if you try to open SharePoint designer from the Site Actions menu?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 
 - you also add the port number.
 - there isn't a machine on the network using that same domain name
 - you don't have an entry in your windows hosts file that points to a different (incorrect) location. 
 - Try opening the site directly with SharePoint Designer instead of using the button from the ribbon
 - iisreset?